# Java executes Apache Hop

Tags: java

I am new to Apache Hop. I recently learned about Hop and wanted to integrate Apache Hop into a Java project. ERROR: Can't run workflow due to plugin missing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trtzH.png)

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].